# Website text appears larger on iPhone in random area

Tags: iphone, css, text, size

http://hycroft.com/concierge.html

The text appears quite large at the bottom of the page when viewing it on my iPhone, and I'm really not sure why?

I definitely need to get this resolved as quickly as possible though as my client noticed - and doesn't like!

Thank you VERY much in advance to anyone who can shine some light on this!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some meta tags and content that does not have to be a static size.  This is an example of one of the many `viewport`/`meta` tags you can use in your `<head></head>` to make a website look good on an iPhone:

```
<meta name="viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 2.3, minimum-scale = 1, maximum-scale = 5" />
```

But the best thing to do is to check out the Apple documentation:

### *[Optimizing for Safari on iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006517)*